# Identity column in ASP.NET Membership database

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to use `SqlMembershipProvider` to manage my users in my application.
The way the provider identifies Users is using a GUI/UniqueIdentifier and the way i identify my users is using a INT (identity) column.
What's the best practice? Do i:

- Rewrite my tables so my users are treated as GUIDs like Membership?
- Create a mapping table to relate a single user to both tables?
- Or other idea?

Answer (score 1):

- You can override all SqlMembershipProvider method that uses identity
- Or adjust them to use mapping table
- But if you still want to use ASP.NET Membership infrastructure, the simplest way is to use GUIDs

Answer (score 1):

It would largely depend on what your current system is like. But if there are no repressions from doing this I would go the KISS way and use the guid as a unique id for the rest of your application.